# how can i rewrite this into a single query - sql optimization

Tags: mysql

how can i optimize the following query?
I'm not sure how to rewrite them into a single query, combine all the joins.

```
other_publisher_views AS (
             SELECT clv.date,
                    clv.streeteasy_page_views,
                    clv.trulia_page_views,
                    clv.zillow_page_views,
                    clv.realtor_page_views
             FROM agent_insights_lt.agent_insights__combined_listing_views AS clv
             JOIN listing_info_raw
                     ON clv.property_id_sha = listing_info_raw.property_id_sha
         ),
         other_publisher_views_by_period AS (
             SELECT is_current_period,
                    start_date,
                    end_date,
                    coalesce(sum(streeteasy_page_views), 0) AS streeteasy_page_views,
                    coalesce(sum(trulia_page_views), 0)     AS trulia_page_views,
                    coalesce(sum(zillow_page_views), 0)     AS zillow_page_views,
                    coalesce(sum(realtor_page_views), 0)    AS realtor_page_views
             FROM periods
             LEFT JOIN other_publisher_views ON
                 other_publisher_views.date BETWEEN periods.start_date
                                                AND periods.end_date
```

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952). As this isn't a *very simple SQL query*, the need for the table definitions, sample data and the desired output is even more necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend building and maintaining a summary table with the 4 page_view subtotals for each day and property_id_sha.

Each night, calculate the subtotals for the previous day.

That way you can produce a report something like the second part quite efficiently.  It would not need `coalesce` and it would sum up the subtotals from the summary table.

More on summary tables: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables